# Is there a way to pass by value all the sub-classes of an pure abstract class to a function in C++?

Tags: c++

Say I had 2 classes `A` and `B`, where `A` is a pure abstract class with a pure virtual function and `B` inherits from `A` and implements the pure virtual function. If I then have a function `g()` that I want to pass any instance of a subclass of `A` by value to (so I could mutate it without changing the original instance), how would you do that?
I know that the following code does not fit my purposes:

```
void g(A myObject) {} //doesn't work since A contains a pure virtual function

void g(A* myObject) {} //code compiles, but changes the original instance
```

Would I just copy the instance and make a pointer to it and pass into a function like above? Or is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best practice here is to leverage `clone()` method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void set_str(std::string) = 0;
    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() = 0;
};

class Derived: public Base
{
private:
    std::string _str;
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() override { 
        return std::make_unique<Derived>(*this); 
    }
    void set_str(std::string str) override {
        this->_str = str;
    }
    void print() override {
        std::cout << this->_str << std::endl;
    }
};

void foo(std::unique_ptr<Base> obj) {
    obj->set_str("inside");
    obj->print();
}

int main() {
    Derived obj;
    obj.set_str("outside");
    foo(obj.clone());
    obj.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So to use this, I would clone the object that was passed into the function inside the function, before mutating it without changing the original object? `f(Base* obj) { Base* c = obj->clone() }`

Comment: Thanks, this does what I need!

Answer (score 1):

What prevent the copy if indeed the pure virtual function in A. If A could be copy created from its child classes, you would have *sliced* the original object and only kept the fields present in A.

If you want to prevent modifications, you could:

- replace the pure virtual function with a function raising an exception. Class A would become creatable while it would still break if you tried to use the function on a non subclassed object.
- insert a A1 class in the hierachy with the above defined function and use it in `g`

This both methods create a copy of the original object and pass that (sliced) copy

You could also use a const reference:

```
void g(const A& myObject);
```

This will pass a reference to the original object, but the compiler will raise an error if you try to modify it.